# Stop a marquee 5 seconds for every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I want to create an marquee that start at first, but every 10 seconds, the marquee will stop for 5 seconds before the marquee start again.

How can I do that?

I only manage to create a timer that stop the marquee after 5 seconds :

```
<script>
    function startLoop() {
    setInterval( "doSomething()", 5000 ); }
    function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById('myMarquee').stop(); }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body onload="startLoop();">
   <marquee direction="right" id="myMarquee">This is a marquee.</marquee>
</body>
```

Comment: as marquee will behave different in each browser (it is not a standard element), you might want to look for [jQuery alternative](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) instead.

Comment: You need some logic to implement it, I have tried to present, you can check. Also you need to change `<body onload="startloop();">` to `<body onload="startLoop();">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few days ago I needed something similar to your problem. I soon figured out that marquee is not a standard element, so you can't use it in cross-browser solutions.

I have extracted the animation part, based on jQuery, I used in my solution, you can see the effect in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FErqP/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="mytext">
        this is a simple text to test custom marquee
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mytext
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    var txt = $("#mytext");
    txt.bind('scroll', function () {
        var el = $(this);
        // Scroll state machine
        var scrollState = el.data("scrollState") || 0;
        el.data("scrollState", (scrollState + 1) % 4);
        switch (scrollState) {
            case 0: // initial wait
                el.css({ left: 0 });
                el.show();
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    el.trigger("scroll");
                }, 5000);
                break;
            case 1: // start scroll
                var delta = el.parent().width() - el.width();
                if (delta < 0) {
                    el.animate({ left: delta }, 2000, "linear", function () {
                        el.trigger("scroll");
                    });
                }
                break;
            case 2: // delay before fade out
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    el.trigger("scroll");
                }, 2000);
                break;
            case 3: // fade out
                el.fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    el.trigger("scroll");
                });
                break;
        }
    }).trigger("scroll");
});​
```

It doesn't do exaclty the same as your requirement, but if you read the code and make some changes to the state-machine, you will get it working :)

Comment: Is this using the JQuery? Currently I have no knowledge on JQuery, but thanks for you reply, I'll try to learn it.

Comment: Yes it is. There are a few jQuery notations you should know. F.e.: execute code onload: `$(function() { // will run onload });`, and select element by CSS rules: `$("#mytext")` selects the element with id "mytext".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the marquee, this should work (In browsers that support the marquee):

```
<script>
    function stopRunning() {
        document.getElementById('myMarquee').stop();
        setInterval("startRunning()", 5000);
    }
    function startRunning() {
        document.getElementById('myMarquee').start();
        setInterval("stopRunning()", 10000);
    }

    //You don't really need a function to start the loop, you can just call startRunning();
    startRunning();
</script>
```

This will make the marquee start running, stop after 10 seconds, start again after 5, and repeat.

Comment: This is a trick that I figured out too, I'll try to improve the code to look nicer and better.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var myMarquee = document.getElementById('myMarquee'); 
run();
function run() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myMarquee.stop();
        setTimeout(function(){
            myMarquee.start();
            run();    
        },5000);   
    },10000);
}
```

see it run at http://jsfiddle.net/gjwYh/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'm not too good in nested function, but yours is definitely reduce the number of line of code.

Answer (score 0):

To implement `every 10 seconds, the marquee will stop for 5 seconds before the marquee start again` You need some logic like. I have used step variable to control the progress. Hope its clear

```
<script>
var step = 1; // marquee is run on load time
function startLoop()
{
    setInterval("doSomething()", 5000 );
}
function doSomething()
{
    if (step == 0) {
        // 5 seconds are passed since marquee stopped
        document.getElementById('myMarquee').start();
        step = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (step == 1) {
            // 5 seconds are passed since marquee started
            step = 2; // Just delay of another 5 seconds before stop
        }
        else
        {
            if (step == 2) {
                // 10  seconds are passed since marquee started
                document.getElementById('myMarquee').stop();
                step = 0;
            }
        }
    }              
}
</script>
```

[**Check Out its Working Here on Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gjwYh/1/). I have also added a timer in a div which will give you ease in checking the behavior of stop and start against time

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply same in angular then you do like this

```
import { Component, OnInit , ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
```

write this under class

```
@ViewChild('myname', {static: false}) myname:ElementRef;
```

to start the loop write this under ngOnInit

```
 setTimeout(()=>{    //<<<---    using ()=> syntax
      this.startRunning()
      console.log("aaa")
 }, 1000);
```

place this code outside of ngOnInit

```
startRunning() {
    setInterval(() =>{
      this.myname.nativeElement.stop();
      setTimeout(() =>{
        this.myname.nativeElement.start();
        console.log("start")
      },2000) 
              console.log("stop")
    }, 4000);
    
  }
```